# Shell scripts specified in _SCRIPTS primary isn't shown in dist tarball

Tags: linux, software-distribution, autoconf, automake

I'm using Automake to maintain the package, there are some shell scripts which don't need to compile, so I install them using _SCRIPT primary:

```
Makefile.am: 

bin_SCRIPTS = script1.sh
```

But the tarball generated with `make dist` doesn't contain this `script1.sh` file. Is there something I missed in the Makefile.am?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `dist_bin_SCRIPTS = script1.sh`.